# Eclipse startup fails in Fedora 12 with the message "JVM terminated. Exit code = -1"

Tags: eclipse, fedora, fedora12

I am using Fedora12.

I have downloaded eclipse-cpp-galileo-SR1-linux-gtk.

I am using Java version "1.6.0_18"

When I start eclipse, I get the following error dialog. What might be the issue?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Could you post your picture on imageshack.us ? tinypic.com is blocked at work, so I do not see your screenshot.

Comment: http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/43/screenshotbv.png

Also, I get the following error when I try to start eclipse from the console besides the above error.


/usr/java/jre1.6.0_18/bin/../lib/i386/client/libjvm.so: cannot enable executable stack as shared object requires: Permission denied

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used to see that message when there was any error in `eclipse.ini`.
Try using **[my `eclipse.ini`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590)** to see if that solve the problem.
In particular, check there is no extra space at the end of each line.

That being said, the error message:

```
/usr/java/jre1.6.0_18/bin/../lib/i386/client/libjvm.so:  
  cannot enable executable stack as shared object requires: Permission denied
```

is probably the real issue here.

Check if this is not related to the fact that most applications are not permitted to run with an executable stack.
See [this article](http://etbe.coker.com.au/2007/10/07/executable-stack-and-shared-objects/).

[This forum](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=234435) suggests:

```
#setsebool -P allow_execstack 1
```

> After reading [SELinux Reveals Bugs in other code](http://danwalsh.livejournal.com/13716.html) and [SELinux Reveals Bugs in other code.](http://danwalsh.livejournal.com/6117.html), I then tried

```
#execstack -c /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0/jre/lib/i386/client/libjvm.so
```

> and this seemed to work also.

---

Update June 2012: [la89ondevg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324929/la89ondevg) mentions in the comments:

> In case command above didn't made the changes so one can select to make changes by going to `System->Administration->SElinux Management` after that select "`Boolean`" and set `Boolean` appropriately or simply search "`allow_execstack`" in filter and set it.
>   This will work same as above command.

Comment: In case command above didn't made the changes so one can select to make changes by going to System->Administration->SElinux Management after that select "Boolean" and set Boolean appropriately or simply search "allow_execstack" in filter and set it. This will work same as above command.

Comment: @la89ondevg interesting, I have included it in the answer for more visibility.